# How to use the profiles from the device in android application?

Tags: android

The profiles from the device(General, Silent or any personalized profile) are needed to be used in the application. How to use them?

Answer (score 1):

Android `AudioManager` - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html lets you access Ringtone, notification, volume and vibration settings etc.

```
audioManager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

Comment: I don't think you can access Profiles which are created by vendors and not by Android platform. Because as I see some Android devices have profile setting and some does'nt